# QGIS 2.99 and python 3.6

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, python-3

I install `QGIS 2.99 development version` on my windows 10. I see in the installation folder I have folders `python27` and `python36. I want to ask can i use python 3.6 to take QGIS python API in standalone app? Does someone have experience with`python 3.6`and`QGIS 2.99` to help me? Are there some steps with others version QGIS to take python api ?

Comment: I would recommend against building any stand-alone applications on the current 2.99 API because it's still under heavy development and will certainly change before the 3.0 release!

Comment: @underdark that i build is easy i thing i just use processing algorithms to automate some things for me...can you help to say how to take python api out of QGIS ?